# List of Dictionaries in python, getting a space in between particular value on printing

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Problem to create a list of dictionaries with three keys name,age and location. On printing the list, I keep Getting a space after the Age value and i don't know how to fix this. Image [Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVKzf.jpg) shows output im getting and the output im supposed to get. I'm new to python so any help is appreciated.

```
import sys
print("Enter the no of student details to be created :")
n=int(input())
if n<=0:
 print ("Invalid Input ")
 exit()
detlist=[]
i=0
for i in range (0,n):
 det={}  
 print("Name:")
 det['Name']=str(input())
 print("Age:")
 x=int(input())
 if x<=10 or x>20:
   print("Invalid Input")
   exit()
 det['Age']=int(x)
 print("Location:")
 det['Location']=str(input())
 detlist.append(det.copy())

print("Here's the list of student details :")
for i in range(0,n):
  print(detlist[i])
print("Enter the training location:")
loc=str(input())
print("Student(s) enrolled in this location:")
for d in detlist:
  if (d['Location']==loc):
    print (d['Name'])
```

Comment: It looks like the person who created the expected output created it by hand without respecting the Python conventions...

Comment: As a side note, about conventions, a perfectly respected one is to use 4 spaces for indents. You can have a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: So there's no way to pass the test?